# fscanf and switch not working

Tags: c, switch-statement, scanf, ungetc

I'm trying to read this .txt file:

> ( 1 2 ( 3 4 ( 5

with this code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
  FILE* f = fopen("teste.txt", "r");
  int i;
  char j;

  while (feof(f) == 0){
    fscanf(f, "%c", &j);

    switch (j) {

      case '(':
        printf("%c ", j);
        break;

      default:
        ungetc(j,f);
        fscanf(f, "%d", &i);
        printf("%d ", i);
        break;

    }
  }
  return 0;
}
```

The output is:

> ( 1 2 2 ( 3 4 4 ( 5 5

and it should be:

> ( 1 2 ( 3 4 ( 5

What am  I doing wrong?

Comment: Probably want `fscanf(f, " %c", &j);`  - add space.

Comment: To avoid trailing garbage make your loop be `while ( fscanf(f, " %c", &j) == 1 )`. [More info](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5431941/while-feof-file-is-always-wrong)

Comment: Also consider checking the result of the `fscanf` within the `default` case, otherwise your program will break on encountering a string with letters in it

Comment: See [`while (!feof(file))` is always wrong](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5431941/while-feof-file-is-always-wrong) for information on why your `while (feof(f) == 0)` loop is a bad idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) Use `int j;`  `fgets()` returns an `unsigned char` or `EOF` 257 different values.  Using a `char` loses information.

2) Do not use `feof()`

```
// while (feof(f) == 0){ 
//  fscanf(f, "%c", &j);
while (fscanf(f, " %c", &j) == 1) {  // note space before %c
```

3) Test `fscanf()` return value

```
// fscanf(f, "%d", &i);    
if (fscanf(f, "%d", &i) != 1) break;
```

Answer (score 0):

use `fgetc` instead of `fscanf` , try this

```
    #include <stdio.h>

int main() {
FILE* f = fopen("teste.txt", "r");
int i;
char j;
char t;
while (feof(f) == 0){

    j = fgetc(f);

    switch (j){

    case '(':
    printf("%c ", j);
    break;

    default:
    ungetc(j,f);
    t = fgetc(f);
    i = atoi(&t);
    printf("%d ", i);
    break;

    }

}
```

Comment: 1) Code has an interesting infinite loop.  Consider if `j = fgetc(f);` results in `j == EOF` and `char` is  `unsigned char`.  Code keeps putting back an `char`.  2) ` i = atoi(&t);` is UB.